# find by xpath only in child of element with c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I have this code :

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> questions = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//fieldset[@data-seleniumrp='Question']"));
foreach (IWebElement question in questions)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> repdispo = question.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@data-selenium-positionquestion]"));
}
```

my collection "questions" have 11 elements, that right !
for each "question" normaly i have 4 elements ... 
but with this code , i have 44 results ( all elements in page ) in "repdispo" ...

how get only childrend element and not all element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really suspect the problem is in the XPath inside the `foreach` loop. You need to add `.` at the beginning of `//` axis to make it relative to current `question` element :

```
".//input[@data-selenium-positionquestion]"
```